# jQuery - .html() Does Not Accept &amp;

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason when I try to add a string with "& (amp)" inside of `.html()` the function throws an unrecognized expression error.  Do you know how I can either convert the `&amp;` string or how I can best insert the string I want to the corresponding selector?

```
var img_description = "Aluminum Desktop Computer, Keyboard &amp; Mouse with Clipping Paths";

$(img_description).html(img_description);
```

Keep in mind that in my code `img_description` is a dynamic variable.

Comment: Can you show us what you're actually doing? You mentioned `.html()`, then later said *selector*, which are two completely different things.

Comment: I've added a code example

Comment: What are you *ultimately* trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to assign this HTML to *something*. It appears you lack the most basic understanding of how jQuery works, I recommend you to [start here](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) before delving any deeper.

Comment: As @AnthonyGrist said, please show us the code, secondly you may encode your string, `encodeURI(stringData)`

Comment: this is not normal question....

Comment: you know if you accept answers to some of your questions you get reputation yourself right?

Answer (score 4):

That's an invalid selector, the first part need to be an element you want to replace the html of. For this example, lets replace the content of a div with ID `test`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/YKhAa/1/

```
$("#test").html(img_description);
```

---

The `#` in front of test is to select a specific ID (in our case, ID of `test`).

You should really familiarize yourself with selectors, here's the link to the API: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

this is fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('p').html('&amp;');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EJSS2/1/

your code is wrong. Your trying to use the html as the selector and the html.

Comment: While `$(window).ready` may work, it doesn't make sense to use `window`, and it **should** be `$(document).ready`. You could put any selector in there - the `.ready()` method internally deals with the `document` no matter what. You would use `.load()` for `window`, but that's unnecessary here because we don't need to wait for images, iframes, etc. to be loaded

Comment: @Ian all I was trying to do was show that you can insert an &amp; into .html().....

Comment: @Liam I completely understand. But you should still use jQuery methods "correctly", even in simple examples. I wasn't trying to invalidate your answer or anything, just wanted to point it out

Comment: @Ian, maybe being a bit grumpy there, updated!

Comment: @Liam No no no, I may be nitpicking, not grumpy though :) I just don't want to confuse the OP or other users

Comment: @Ian, whoops! think I gave you the wrong end of the stick, meant **Im** being grumpy. Wow this is incredibly polite! :)

Comment: @Liam Haha I see, sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do makes no sense; you can't create a jQuery object out of an arbitrary string, so it's being interpreted as a selector for elements. The issue with the ampersand (&) in that selector is covered in the [documentation for selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

Even if you do that, however, the first part isn't going to do anything useful for you, so you'll see nothing happen. You need to first either select at least one element or create a new one, before you can use `.html()` to set its HTML content (which will happily accept a string containing an `&` without you needing to do anything).